# java String.split(regex) design

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm importing a file with umpteen lines of `"##,##"`. Each number can be one or two digits.

I'd like to use `String.split(regex)` to get the two numbers without the adjacent quote marks.

Understanding that I could nibble off the first and last character and use a non-regex split, I'm hoping that there is a regular expression that will make this more graceful.

Suggestions?

EDIT:

```
In: "12,3"  
Out: 12  
      3
```

Comment: what do you mean with "_non-regex split_"? Also, can you provide a input/output example. Should `"12,34"` become `12,34` or `12` and `34`?

Comment: If I use String.split(",") I get the two halves. Each has a single quote mark on it... ok - not truly "non-regex" but not really using the strength of regex...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using a regexp `\"(d+),(d+)\"`. Then using `Pattern.matcher(input)` instead of `String.split`, and obtaining your digits by `Matcher.group(int)`.

Please consider following snippet:

```
String line = "\"1,31\"";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(\\d+),(\\d+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    // do whatever with the numbers
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all double-quotes characters in each line then split the string by ,

```
String toSplit = "\"##,##\"";
String[] splitted = toSplit.replaceAll("\"", "").split(",");
```

Using `\"` in the `toSplit` string to simulate the `"##,##"` string.

Answer (score 0):

You could split at the quotes as well but that would result in an array of length 4. Unfortunately, there's no way of *splitting* a string and *removing* others characters from the same string in one call using `String#split`.

As an alternative, you could use Apache's `StringUtils`:

```
String[] n = StringUtils.removeStart( StringUtils.removeEnd( "##,##", "\""), "\"").split(",");
```

Edit: as a side note, using `StringUtils` would allow for missing quotes at the start or end of the input string. If you're sure they're always present, a simple `substring(...)` might be sufficient. (credits go to @Ingo)

Comment: You could split the substring 1 too length-1

Comment: @Ingo which substring do you mean? Could you elaborate?

Comment: it should be obvious, shouldn't it? If I can't split "xx,xx" because of the quotes, I can split the substring xx,xx

Comment: @Ingo now I understand your sentence. That's obvious, you're right. But with respect to my answer, I didn't understand your comment, since I meant to clearly state that it's not possible with _one_ call of _split_ alone - you'd need at least a substring or whatever to remove the quotes _first_ ;)

Comment: I did mean it as a supplement to your answer - one way of getting rid of the enclosing characters. Substring should cheaper than all the solutions that use replaceAll, etc.